# Как показать уведомление конкретному пользователю телеграм группы?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть бот который отправляет в группу сообщение с кнопкой после текста (*inline_keyboard*)

И соответственно скрипт ловит все нажатия на эту кнопку.

Я хочу чтобы когда пользователь нажимает кнопку, то в группу должно приходить сообщение (или какое-то уведомление), которое будет видеть только пользователь который нажал эту кнопку. (разумеется id пользователя получаю, но не понимаю как отправить сообщение или уведомление в группу конкретно для определенного пользователя).

Буду благодарен за информацию!

Comment: Насколько мне известно, в группе нет ограничений по видимости на сообщения. Нужно отправлять в лс пользователю. Если ошибаюсь, пожалуйста, расскажите про возможности.

Comment: @SergeyK. нашел решение) добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть метод `answerCallbackQuery` в котором нужно передать **callback_query_id** и **text**  уведомления.

Более подробно описано тут https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery